# Which connector in datastage can be used to connect to AWS Oracle Rds

Tags: amazon-web-services, connector, datastage

Our OnPrem database is migrating to Oracle AWS RDS. I am struggling to find which datastage connector can be used?

Answer (score 0):

Use either Oracle Connector or IBM provided DataDirect JDBC driver for Oracle.

For Oracle Connector, make sure to install Oracle Client and able to connect to Oracle DB on AWS RDS using sqlplus from Engine tier command line.

For IBM provided DataDirect JDBC driver for Oracle update below in isjdbc.config file under $DSHOME
CLASSPATH=/opt/IBM/InformationServer/ASBNode/lib/java/ISoracle.jar
CLASS_NAME=com.ibm.isf.jdbc.oracle.OracleDriver

Use below JDBC URL in JDBC Connector.
jdbc:datadirect:oracle://server_name:1521;ServiceName=your_servicename
OR
jdbc:datadirect:oracle://server_name:1521;sid=your_sidname